# how to remove two json objects with same id

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a .json file with the following contents:

```
[
         {
                    "id": "1234",
                    "day": "Monday",
                    "course": "Math110",

         },
         {
                    "id": "1234",
                    "day": "Wednesday",
                    "title": "Math110",

         },
         {
                    "id": "1345",
                    "day": "Tuesday",
                    "title": "Economics210",

         }
]
```

How can I remove all the objects with id "1234" in Javascript? *(note there are two objects with the same ID)*

Would `delete["1234"]` work?

Comment: no it wouldn't, as that isn't even a thing - the question is, do you wish to mutate an existing array, or can your code handle creating a new array without those items?

Comment: lol i forgot it was like delete json["1234"] not delete["1234"] lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `delete` operator because its for [deleting a property in an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). You actually want to delete an object inside an array.

Use the good old `for` loop and [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
var inputArray = [{
    "id": "1234",
    "day": "Monday",
    "course": "Math110",

  },
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "title": "Math110",

  },
  {
    "id": "1345",
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "title": "Economics210",

  }
];

var deleteId = "1234";

for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
  if (inputArray[i].id === deleteId) {
    inputArray.splice(i, 1);
    i = i-1;
  }
}

console.log(inputArray);
```

Note: If you are fine with creating another array and not modifying the existing array, use `Array.filter()` as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that worked! Do you know how I can save inputArray to a .json file?

Comment: @haxtar you will need to send the JSON data to backend and have the backend save it to the file. Frontend JS alone cannot write to a .json file

Answer (score 2):

Use `.filter` to filter out elements of an array:

```js
const input = [{
    "id": "1234",
    "day": "Monday",
    "course": "Math110",

  },
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "title": "Math110",

  },
  {
    "id": "1345",
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "title": "Economics210",

  }
];
const output = input.filter(({ id }) => id !== '1234');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the JSON to an array and then use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get a new array which doesn't have the objects with id `"1234"`:

```js
const json = '[{"id":"1234","day":"Monday","course":"Math110"},{"id":"1234","day":"Wednesday","title":"Math110"},{"id":"1345","day":"Tuesday","title":"Economics210"}]';

const result = JSON.parse( json ).filter( obj => obj.id !== "1234" );

console.log( JSON.stringify( result, null, ' '.repeat(8) ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete by specifying the position of the item in the array:

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": "1234",
    "day": "Monday",
    "course": "Math110",

  },
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "title": "Math110",

  },
  {
    "id": "1345",
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "title": "Economics210",

  }
];
arr.forEach(function(item, i){
  if(item.id == "1234")
    delete arr[i];
});

console.log(arr.filter(j => j))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
items = [
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "day": "Monday",
        "course": "Math110",

    },
    {
         "id": "1234",
         "day": "Wednesday",
         "title": "Math110",

    },
    {
         "id": "1345",
         "day": "Tuesday",
         "title": "Economics210",

     }
];

items.filter(function(item) { 
   return item.id !== '1234';  
});
```